# How to clone a record in a custom entity & the related child records on click of a custom button 'Clone Record' on the form?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I am using Dynamic CRM 2015 On-Premise.

I want to clone a record in a custom entity & the related child records on click of a custom button 'Clone Record' on the form.

Please provide some example on how to clone a record in a custom entity & the related child records on click of a custom button 'Clone Record' on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a Code Activity which would:

1. Read Parent
2. Read Children
3. Create Clone of parent, grab id
4. create clone of children, using the record id grabbed at #3 as parent

No need to get much fancy, just go through the steps sequentially.

To fire the code, you can create an `Action` (which would be invoked by the ribbon) containing the aforementioned Code Activity